# Mocha coverage task fails and propagates exception to grunt which aborts the whole execution

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I am using **grunt-mocha-istanbul** and have a task which runs the coverage through set of test files. The reporter is set to **mocha-junit-reporter** which generates the mocha test results XML file and the coverage report formats are set to *cobertura* and *html*.

For some reason, an error in the tests causes the whole task to fail and not just to get details on the failed test in the end report.
I ran the grunt task using **--stack** argument which produced the following:

```
Error: Task "mocha_istanbul:coveralls" failed.
at Task.<anonymous> (~\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:205:15)
at null._onTimeout (~\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:241:33)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

As you can see, this hides the original error somehow.

I defined a separate task to just run the tests and saw the issue but it has nothing to do with how the test execution in terms of callbacks gets handled.

So my question is, how can I intercept such propagated exceptions and provide more detailed information on what actually happened?